# Retrieving User activity from mssql for particular user else for all user

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReadUserActivity]

@fromdate datetime,
@todate datetime,
@EmployeeID int,
@Activity varchar(255)
AS
    BEGIN
  Begin Transaction 

 Select * from dbo.ActivityLog where ActivityDate<=@fromdate and ActivityDate>=@todate
commit transaction
END
```

I want these things,
 If data required for all users, pass Activity as "All" else pass EmployeeID
If data required for all activities, pass Activity as "All" else pass Particular activity

Comment: What is the schema of ActivityLog table?

Comment: Activity varchar(255),EmployeeID int,ActivityDate datetime for the table of dbo.Activity

Comment: What if someone wants to define an activity called `All`? It would probably be a better idea to use the specific "no information passed" marker, `NULL`, to indicate that no `@EmployeeID` or `ActivityID` is being requested. Also, unless you're using some pretty unusual naming, I'd always expect a `@fromDate` to be earlier (or equal to) a `@toDate`. It's therefore unlikely that there will be any rows with an `ActivityDate` value that's simultaneously earlier than `@fromDate` and later than `@toDate`.

Comment: is there any typo error in the problem statement "If data required for all users, pass Activity as "All" else pass EmployeeID". Would it be "If data required for all users, pass EmplyeeID as NULL else pass EmployeeID"?

Comment: Can EmployeeID or Activity fields be NULL in the table?

Comment: No,EmployeeID is foriegn key of EmployeeMaster, Activity field is get the details of the employees who retrieved the information of which table and what error/saved occured for that particula user while creating or updating

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as this? or did I miss something ...

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReadUserActivity]
    @fromdate datetime,
    @todate datetime,
    @EmployeeID int,
    @Activity varchar(255)
AS

    IF @Activity = 'ALL'
        Select * from dbo.ActivityLog where ActivityDate<=@fromdate and ActivityDate>=@todate
    ELSE
        Select * from dbo.ActivityLog 
            where ActivityDate<=@fromdate and ActivityDate>=@todate AND EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```